# How to automatically call constructor by type name without reflection in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, deserialization, game-engine, game-development

I'm currently writing a game from scratch in C# (.NET 7) and I would like to automate mapping data to script constructors without reflection (because of Native AOT).

I already have a way to serialize and de-serialize the class fields themselves, but I'm lost when it comes to actually determining which object type to create when reading in a block of data, like e.g. Unity when it has to bind YAML data to a Component as part of an Entity.

In my eyes the most naive approach would be to have a type ID at the start of each data block and a switch statement that calls the constructor of the type with that ID as the name, like this:

```cs
public static IAsset Instantiate(string id, byte[] data)
{
    switch (id)
    {
        case "Player": return new Player(data);
        case "Vehicle": return new Vehicle(data);
        case "Weapon": return new Weapon(data);
        default: throw new ArgumentException();
    }
}
```

This would be fine if the amount of available asset types were very low, but I'm assuming there's going to be a ton of different scripts down the line.

Is there any way this can be done automatically for every script at compile or run time?

Comment: you explicitly excluded the most straightforward solution - reflection. i'm not aware of any other way to achieve this - except by hand.

Comment: Code generation perhaps?

Comment: Source Generation seems like a good shout! @FranzGleichmann I know, but I don't really have a choice since Native AOT doesn't allow for that kind of reflection.

Comment: `return Activator.CreateInstance(id, new object[] { data });` wouldn't work? Wouldn't call that reflection.

Comment: I thought about that too, but it doesn't work since the overload for calling a specific constructor expects a Type and not a string as the first argument.

Comment: Bummer. Was reading https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/coreclr/nativeaot/docs/reflection-free-mode.md and it felt like it should work but the doc is talking about CreateInstance<T> :(

Comment: Might help to maintain a central string to type mapping (and generate that code from something) if you need that more frequent then in the shown code.

Comment: I tried your example and it works in regular IL but not in .NET Native.

Comment: AFAIK you can [use](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/coreclr/nativeaot/docs/reflection-in-aot-mode.md) reflection even in AOT mode. If none of the built-in assumption strategies work you can add an [rd.xml](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/coreclr/nativeaot/docs/rd-xml-format.md) file to help the compiler what types should be included even if they are not discovered by the default dependency analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a lookup table (i.e. a dictionary of delegates).

```
static readonly List<string,Func<byte[],IAsset>> _masterList = new List<string,Func<byte[],IAsset>>
{
    { "Player", x => new Player(x) },
    { "Vehicle", x => new Vehicle(x) },
    { "Weapon", x => new Weapon(x) }
};

public static IAsset Instantiate(string id, byte[] data)
{
   if (!_masterList.ContainsKey(id)) throw new ArgumentException("Invalid ID");
   return _masterList[id](data);
}
```

Comment: I paired this together with Source Generation and it works like a charm, thanks!